# Middle click mouse in Angular 6

Tags: angular

How to open routerlinks in a new tab with middle click mouse in Angular 6?
I want to open every link in a new tab. 
for example

`<button mat-icon-button color="accent" [routerLink]="['/edit', a.Id]">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</button>`

Comment: To open links in new tabs you have to add `target="_blank"` to your hrefs. For the middle click, this will open to new tab by default (handled by the browser, not the web page). Not sure what this question is asking for.

Comment: @DavidLee These are not hrefs, they are `<button>` elements which don't have `target` as an attribute

Answer (score 8):

The auxclick event is fired when a  any non-left mouse button has been pressed and released on an element.

```
<button mat-icon-button color="accent" [routerLink]="['/edit', a.Id]" 
  (auxclick)="onClick($event)">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
onClick(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   if(e.which==2){
     window.open('/users/'+a.Id);
   }

}
```

Comment: e.which is deprecated, you should now use e.button to identify which button you clicked. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Answer (score 4):

```
<a  (click)="open(a.Id,$event)" href="/edit/{{item.Id}}" target="_blank">
  <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</a>
```

and then

```
 open(id: number, event: MouseEvent) {
    // prevent href to fire.
    // href will work only for middle mouse button click
    event.preventDefault(); 

    // open in new tab when click + ctrl
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      return window.open('/edit/' + id, '_blank')
    }


     this.router.navigate(['/userAd', id]);
    
  }
```

Comment: This one is helpful when you need functionalities of the button and the `<a>` at the same time.